# Validation to check if coordinates for my triangle are a valid input in java which means a triangle is properly constructed

Tags: java, swing, validation

I am taking coordinates as input like below :

```
System.out.print("Enter the three X coordinates for Triangle (x1cord,x2cord,x3cord) :");
int x1cord = input.nextInt();
int x2cord = input.nextInt();
int x3cord = input.nextInt();
int x[] = {x1cord,x2cord,x3cord};

System.out.print("Enter the three Y coordinates for Triangle (y1cord,y2cord,y3cord) :");
int y1cord = input.nextInt();
int y2cord = input.nextInt();
int y3cord = input.nextInt();
int y[] = {y1cord,y2cord,y3cord};

shape = FillComponent.drawTriangle(x, y);
```

And constructing a triangle using :

`Shape triangle = new Polygon(x[], y[], 3);`

I want to check if user is entering valid coordinates. ---- Need help on this.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "valid"? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: If this is a Swing GUI, then you're much better off avoiding using `System.out.print(...)` and Scanner, and much better off getting the user to input data into the GUI.

Comment: by valid i meant that coordinates should be such that it would lead to a proper triangle be it scalene , isosceles or equilateral.. Co ordinates should not be out of range which for example lead to open ended lines.

Answer (score 4):

The coordinates form a valid triangle if the three points are not in a line (the sum of the length of any two sides must exceed the length of the remaining side).

Therefore, using your coordinate variables, here is the triangle validation logic (using `java.awt.Point`):

```
Point vertex1 = new Point(x1cord, y1cord);
Point vertex2 = new Point(x2cord, y2cord);
Point vertex3 = new Point(x3cord, y3cord);

double side1 = Math.abs(vertex1.distance(vertex2));
double side2 = Math.abs(vertex2.distance(vertex3));
double side3 = Math.abs(vertex3.distance(vertex1));

boolean valid = side1 + side2 > side3
             && side2 + side3 > side1
             && side3 + side1 > side2;

if (!valid) {
    System.out.println("The entered coordinates do not form a triangle");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing, you can write code as follows

you will get value from

```
String cordinate_1=text_field1.getText();
```

And use the following method to check whether the user input is Integer or Not

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
 try  
    {  
     double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
     }  
   catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
   return false;  
   }  
return true;  
 }
```